# Request to other person to share their google calendar via API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to subscribe to the other person's calendar via API?

Using the UI, one would do it by going into their google calendar -> Settings -> Add Calendar -> [Subscribe to Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/addcalendar)

Then provide an email of a person who's calendar I want to subscribe to and send access request if needed

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish that flow programmatically?

Can't find it in the docs, but maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: If the owner of the calendar, has authorized an application you could programaticly give user number 2 access to that calendar by running a permissions.insert

Comment: @DaImTo wow indeed, thanks for the idea! Then I just need to send an invitation email or build a dedicated "request access page" explaining why they need to proceed, then redirect them to google consent screen, and once they finish it, add their calendar. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.